# Name Label overlapping each time it is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, label

Our app has a social feed with a name label similar to Facebook with a FeedController and FeedCell class. Each time we scroll back to a previously loaded cell, it reloads, so the name label becomes darker, the text becomes bolder and starts to overlap. How do we fix this? We tried the prepareToReuse method and setting the cell's label to nil, but that did not help. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're regenerating the label and adding it to your cell's content view every time that the label is reused.

Inside your `FeedCell` class, make sure to only initiate your interface elements in your initializer. From there, you can fill your cell with data in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of your `UITableViewDataSource`.

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, make sure to not add any views to the cell as this could contribute to the issue you're describing. As a rule of thumb, I make sure to initialize the views in the cell subclass's initializer, and only manipulate properties of these views (like `hidden`, `alpha`, etc) when working with the cells.

Moving forward, you can use `prepareForReuse` to clear any data from your cell that may be leftover from the previous time the cell was used. In many cases though, this isn't necessary as the data will be changed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually ended up fixing it in a different way by deleting all the subviews on each cell when it loads in these lines:for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }. Is there anything wrong with doing it this way verses the way that you described?

Comment: Nothing wrong, per se, but your cells will layout a little bit slower because you're not reusing your views and will therefore incur additional CPU time.